# Refactoring AzureML pipeline into dbx pipeline with deployment file

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-dbx

**My company is in the process of migrating all our pipelines over to Databricks from AzureML**, and I have been tasked with refactoring one of our existing pipelines made with azureml-sdk (using functions such as PipelineData, PythonScriptStep etc.), and converting it into a dbx pipeline which uses a deployment.yml file.

I have found this ["Deployment file reference"](https://dbx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/deployment/) on dbx documentation page, and I think it's quite adequate compared to some of AzureML's documentation. However, if I had an example project to compliment that page, it would help me greatly to put it into practice.

**Is there any repos/sources which gives an example of building a dbx pipeline which uses .py-files instead of notebooks?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, if I had an example project to compliment that page, it would help me greatly to put it into practice.

Please take a look at the [Quickstart](https://dbx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/python/python_quickstart/) doc which generates a sample project and walks you through it step by step.

If you're looking for more profound and in-depth example with orientation towards MLOps practices, take a look at the following session - [MLOps on Databricks: A How-To Guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JApPzAnbfPI). It also links to an example repo with `dbx`.